# Is there a way to add 2 days to a date string and update another field with the results?

Tags: powershell

I have a large file containing records where a date string in each record needs to be incremented by 2 days which will then update the field to the right of it which contains dashes '-----' with that date.   For example, a record contains the following record data:

```
 1440149049845_20191121000000 11/22/2019 **--------** 0.000 0.013
```

I want to replace the '--------' dashes with 11/24/2019 (2 days added to the date 11/22/2019) so that it shows as:

```
 1440149049845_20191121000000 11/22/2019 **11/24/2019** 0.000 0.013
```

In addition I need the field containing **0.000** to be replaced with 0.412 so the entire updated record would render as the following:

```
 1440149049845_20191121000000 11/22/2019 **11/24/2019** **0.412** 0.013
```

Can this be coded in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. You can do something similar to the following:

```
$a = '1440149049845_20191121000000 11/22/2019 **--------** 0.000 0.013'
$null = $a -match '\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}' 
$a -replace '-{2,}',([datetime]$matches.0).adddays(2).tostring('MM/dd/yyyy') -replace '\b0\.000\b','0.412'
```

**Explanation:**

`-match` uses regex to pattern match against a string. Successful matches are stored in the automatic variable `$Matches`. `$Matches` is a hash table of key-value pairs for each capture group. The value of each capture can be accessed with a dot reference by name. Since we didn’t specify a capture group name and only used the default group, `$Matches.0` retrieves the matches value.

`\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'` is a regex pattern that matches a date pattern of `MM/dd/yyyy`. The match can be retrieved from `$Matches.0`.

Using the `[datetime]` accelerator, the date string is converted into a datetime object where we can have access to the `AddDays()` method.

`\b0\.000\b` is another regex pattern that matches `0.000` without any other adjacent letters or numbers. Note how the `.` must be escaped with `\` in order to be literal because the `.` has special meaning in regex.

At times it is easier to just string together multiple operators. This is the purpose of having multiple `-replace` operators. Each output is fed into the next operator.

Comment: AdminOfThings

That looks what I need. However, testing your code in PS, I get this error:

       Unexpected token '.0' in expression or statement.

Comment: That could be a PowerShell version issue. I am testing on 5.1. You could replace `$matches.0` with `$matches[0]`. Make sure there are no quotes around `([datetime]$matches.0).adddays(2).tostring('MM/dd/yyyy')` also.

Comment: You  were right. I was using an older version of PowerShell and just upgraded to 5.1 which eliminated the error.  Now all I need to do is code the script to get the contents of the file containing this string to update each of the records. Do you have a code sample that would allow me to update all records in a file report.txt using your sample code?